# Python - error when using PyVsta + Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, vtk, pyvista

I am creating a program with GUI. I use Tkinter and visualize data in 3D by PyVista.

Data is drawn in a separate window of PyVista. Everything works fine until I close the PyVista window.

At this point, the tkinter window freezes. After stopping the script, an error is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draw.py", line 46, in <module>
    event, values = window.read()
  File "lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10067, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
  File "lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10195, in _read
    Window._root_running_mainloop.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have read a lot of articles about this but have not found an answer. `notebook=False` doesn't help.

I also saw articles about VTK errors, but the error I get is not like this.

Can you help with this?

Comment: Tkinter used by PySimpleGui

Comment: 1. you can [edit] your question to add information, rather than posting comments. 2. when you say "after stopping the script", do you mean by pressing ctrl+c or something similar? Because that's what the error suggests, so it's not directly related to your problem. 3. How do tkinter and pyvista interact in your code? Could you put together a very small example (a [mcve]) that demonstrates the issue so that we can try debugging this?